# Moving Wordpress site to Docker: Error establishing DB connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

Ive been making new sites with Wordpress & Docker recently and have a reasonable grasp of how it all works and Im now looking to move some established sites into Docker.

Ive been following this guide:

https://stephenafamo.com/blog/moving-wordpress-docker-container/

I have everything setup as it should be but when I go to my domain.com:1234 I get the error message 'Error establishing a database connection'. I have changed 'DB HOST' to 'mysql' in wp-config.php as advised and all the DB details from the site Im bringing in are correct.

I have attached to the mysql container and checked that the db is there and with the right user and also made sure the pw is correct via mysql CLI too.

SELinux is set to permissive and I havent changed any dir/file ownership nor permissions and for the latter dirs are all 755 and files 644 as they should be.

Edit: I should mention that database/data and everything under that seem to be owned by user/group 'polkitd input' instead of root.

Docker logs aren't really telling me much either apart from the 500 error messages for the WP container when I browse the site on port 1234 (as expected though).

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  example_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: example_db
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123 # any random string will do
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydomin_db # the name of your mysql database
      MYSQL_USER: my domain_me # the name of the database user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password123 # the password of the mysql user

  example:
    depends_on:
      - example_db
    image: wordpress:php7.1 # we're using the image with php7.1
    container_name: example
    ports:
      - "1234:80"
    restart: always
    links:
      - example_db:mysql
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Suggestions most welcome as Im out of ideas!

Comment: I think you need to pass those things in WP container as well      
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: example_db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
I had similar issues before.

Comment: just tried that and it didnt work unfortunately. Edit: or do I need to change the DB variables MYSQL_DATABASE to WORDPRESS or vide-versa?

Comment: so I tried something like that for the WP container under environment: by passing things like this WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my domain_db but its still the same problem and trying with something like WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE} threw errors about the variable not existing so setting them as empty strings instead so I guess its not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following compose script. I tried and tested. It works fine.

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db_server
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123 # any random string will do
      MYSQL_DATABASE: udb_test # the name of your mysql database
      MYSQL_USER: me_prname # the name of the database user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password123 # the password of the mysql user

  example:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:php7.1 # we're using the image with php7.1
    container_name: wp-web
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: me_prname
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password123
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: udb_test
    ports:
      - "1234:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

Let me know if you encounter further issues.

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work for me though so at this point I think theres some other problem on my side such as perhaps my .sql file being corrupt? I will take a closer look and try with a different site & db and report back, thanks again.

Comment: well, that's weird! maybe do a docker cleanup and try again. I tried it on a fresh setup. good luck and post back if you face further issues.

Comment: still no progress, I have been trying on my local Centos7 machine and a cloud centos7 vm and I can't even get to the 'Error establishing DB connection' now, instead I can bring all the containers up without any errors but then when I try to open the site it just hangs for a long time and eventually drops the connection and in the mysql container logs it has errors like this EDIT -Nevermind it seems to be working, its insanely slow though, I can see all my sites content though. It does seem there are quite a few people discussing problems with getting the db to work on GitHub though

Comment: ..and there do seem to be a few problems to get around with Docker on Centos/Fedora eg having to change the docker-storage driver to get it to work eg https://help.nextcloud.com/t/docker-container-fails-with-ah00534-apache2-configuration-error-no-mpm-loaded/29491. I think your answer did help though so I will accept that.

Comment: well, I have not tested this on Centos/Fedora. Will see if I can get a hold of one test machine. Definitely sounds like an issue with Docker itself. Good Luck with that!

Answer (score 8):

With the new version of docker-compose it will look like this (if you don't want to use PhpMyAdmin you can leave it out):

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  wp-data:
networks:
  wp-back:

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - wp-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wp-user
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp-pass
    ports:
      - 8889:3306
    networks:
      - wp-back

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: wp-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp-pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    networks:
      - wp-back

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8888:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp-user
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp-pass
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress-files:/var/www/html
    container_name: wordpress-site
    networks:
      - wp-back
```

The database volume is a named  volume wp-data, while the wordpress html is a bind-mount to your current directory ./wordpress-files .

Comment: thanks, I already accepted the other guys comment but I do want to use phpmyadmin actually so will give this a go

Comment: Allright! You can find a lot of info in following this tutorial: [https://github.com/Nxtra/Docker-Compose-Wordpress](https://github.com/Nxtra/Docker-Compose-Wordpress)

Comment: I had tried other versions in docker toolbox with no luck but this one worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Something crucial that had me stuck for a while was the `networks: - wp-back` for the DB container. Without that you will not be able to connect to the DB from Wordpress.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that the `wp-config.php` file has same credentials defined for `db_user`, `db_password` as in `docker-composer yml` file. I too had similar problem i deleted all the files and re-installed and saw that `docker-composer up -d` would start everything but the `wp-config.php` file contents for mysql settings were not defined as in docker. so i changed it accordingly and started working eventually

Answer (score 1):

if you want it all in one container you can refer this repo here,
https://github.com/akshayshikre/lamp-alpine/tree/development

Here from lamp-alpine image is used
Then mysql, php, apache2 (lamp stack) is installed and copied local wordpress demosite and db for demo purpose

if you do not want any kind of continuous integration part ignore .circleci folder
Check docker-compose file and Dockerfile, Environment variables are in .env file

Comment: I actually want to have WP and MYSQL separate but I will check that out too thanks

Answer (score 1):

I share with you my approach

Show running version, question to see if all is well on your side!

```
$ docker --version && docker-compose --version
```

run Docker Copose file

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

after you wait fast forward

show running containers and name of the Wordpress Container is listening on port 8000

```
 $ docker ps
```

you will see the name of your WordPress container on the table as follows if you have followed the steps listed on their site
https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES

xxxxxxxxxxxx        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   cms_wordpress_1

xxxxxxxxxxxx        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    cms_db_1
```

and if you check your browser with the address : [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000)
you will get the message "error establishing DB connection"

launch bash inside the Wordpress container

```
$ docker exec -it cms_wordpress_1 bash
```

apt update fails as there is no connectivity

```
$ apt update
```

open up new terminal and show current Firewalld configuration

```
$ sudo cat /etc/firewalld/firewalld-workstation.conf | greb 'FirewallBackend'
currently set to 'nftables'
```

set value to 'iptables'

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/FirewallBackend=nftables/FirewallBackend=iptables/g' /etc/firewalld/firewalld-workstation.conf
```

confirme new value

```
$ sudo cat /etc/firewalld/firewalld-workstation.conf | grep 'FirewallBackend'
```

restart Firwalld service to apply change

```
$ sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

Refresh the running Wordpress session in your browser and that's good.
good work.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases a probable cause of this issue could be, you have made volumes using `docker compose up` and then when you did `docker compose down` you expected the volumes to be deleted as well as the docker images, but this is not how it works.

From the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) you could read this:

> For data that needs to persist between updates, use host or named volumes.

It implicitly means that named volumes will not get deleted with `down`, so what happens is, when you do an `up` and then add a row to a table and then do a subsequent `down`, then on the next `up` you will get the same old volume and so querying the same table would give you the same row you created previously!

What does this have to do with the error `Error establishing DB connection`, you may ask. To answer your question, let's assume one scenario: What if you changed some MYSQL passwords in the docker compose file in between running the `down` command and the second `up` command?

MYSQL keeps **its own data** just like any other data in its tables, so when you do the second `up`, Docker loads the old volume (the one created by the first `up`) and thus the old credential information will be used by MYSQL and Docker will not even have the opportunity to insert your new information (the ones you changed in the docker compose file) in the administration tables. So obviously, you will be rejected.

The solution thus now would be very simple. To fix it, either do:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

to remove the named volumes as well as the images when running the `down`, or do:

```
docker volume rm [volname]
```

if you've done the down before, and now you want to delete the named volumes.

Comment: To see a list of your volume names run `docker volume ls`.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this tutorials ,https://stephenafamo.com/blog/moving-wordpress-docker-container/, your site wil not work properly. Coz It doesn't restore database and you need to restore manually .sql dump file existed in initdb.d dir by using this command.

```
cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE
```

I also stuck in this and my CSS are not working properly.
Please let me know when you have new idea .

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the database matches:

`WORDPRESS_DB_NAME/WORDPRESS_DB_USER/WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD` must match with db explicitly.

2. try use `links` instead of `depends`:

some system/docker version may have restrictions of communicating between containers.